# $C^1$ function on a convex subset of $\mathbf{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am working on the following problem given in class. Say we have a $C^1$-function $\varphi:X\to\mathbf{R}^n,$ where $X\subset\mathbf{R}^n$ is a convex set, ie. $a+\lambda(b-a)\in X$ for all $a,b\in X,$ and $0\leq\lambda\leq 1.$

I aim to show that for $a,b\in X,$ and $k=b-a$ that
$$\|\varphi(b)-\varphi(a)-k\|\leq\int^1_0\|(D\varphi)(a+\lambda k)-I\|\|k\|d\lambda.$$ ($I$ is the identity matrix)

It is recommended that I show that
$$\|\varphi(b)-\varphi(a)\|\leq\int^1_0\|(D\varphi)(a+\lambda k)\|\|k\|d\lambda$$
in order to get my result. Here's what I've done so far. First I have shown (by a lemma used in the proof of Picard's theorem) that for $x\in\mathbf{R}^n$
$$\int^1_0\langle(D\varphi)(a+\lambda k)(k),x\rangle d\lambda=\langle \varphi(a+k)-\varphi(a),x\rangle.$$ However, I'm having some trouble going from here. It looks like I'm on the right track, but the next step is just out of reach. How would you recommend I go about getting to this result? I thought first of all to take $x=\varphi(b)-\varphi(a),$ then I have 
$$\|\varphi(b)-\varphi(a)\|^2=\int^1_0\langle(D\varphi)(a+\lambda k)(k),\varphi(b)-\varphi(a)\rangle d\lambda,$$ but I'm not sure how to proceed. Help appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the triangle inequality on the last integral, i.e. use that

$$
\big| \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx \big| \leq \int_0^1 | f(x) | \,dx.
$$

If you are still stuck after that, have a look at the spoiler below:

> Then you can use a technique which is sometimes called the "flop", i.e. if you have $$ a^2 \leq C \cdot a,$$ then this implies something about $a$ itself.

Comment: So, do you mean $\int^1_0\langle(D\varphi)(a+\lambda k)(k),\varphi(b)-\varphi(a)\rangle d\lambda\leq\int^1_0\|(D\varphi)(a+\lambda k)\|\|k\|\|\varphi(b)-\varphi(a)\|d\lambda$? I didn't know that was a valid thing to do (if it is, great, but I was previously ignorant of it).

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is called the triangle inequality (for integrals). Basically, all you are using is that $f \leq |f|$, so that $\int f \,dx \leq \int |f|\,dx$. Of course, after that you have to estimate $|\langle x, y \rangle| \leq \Vert x \Vert \cdot \Vert y \Vert$ and stuff like that. About which of these things are you unsure?

Comment: Oh, had just never thought to do that before, the inequality makes sense now. So essentially now that $\int^1_0\|(D\varphi)(a+\lambda k)\|\|k\|\|\varphi(b)-\varphi(a)\|d\lambda\geq\|\varphi(b)-\varphi(a)\|^2$ I divide by $\|\varphi(b)-\varphi(a)\|$ when it is nonzero (and when it is zero the result is trivial anyway), I'm guessing. If not correct me, but thanks for the help

Comment: If so, I think I can immediately conclude the final inequality is true by replacing $\varphi(x)$ with $\varphi(x)-x.$ Thank you for helping. Will give +1 when I can log in to my main account.

Comment: Yes, exactly. This "triangle inequality" is very important, you shoud remember it :)

Comment: Ha just to clarify, I do know of the triangle inequality in general. I haven't got to this point in my education still not knowing of that inequality, I'm not a complete clown =)

Comment: Thats not what I thought :) Maybe my last comment was written badly. I meant this specific form of the triangle inequality (i.e. for integrals).